# Best location for Craft development? Local or Server? Subfolder of production?

Tags: server

What's the best practice for development Craft installations? I think I would like to work on the production web server but in a hidden folder either upstream from my public HTML or as a subfolder.

Does it matter where I install and develop my Craft site? Looking for easy migration when I want to go live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to develop locally, ideally managed with a version control system like Git and then push your site to your server. Craft handles a multi-environment workflow very well.

[From the Craft docs on Mult-Environment configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs)

[A good screencast from Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/articles/multi-environment-workflows)

There are also several questions and answers dealing with this topic in Stack Exchange here.